# an expression for someone else taking over a project at the very end, then taking credit for it

Tags: business-language

There's an expression I can't remember about someone else taking over a project at the very end, and taking credit for it - something like taking it the last mile, taking it in for the touchdown...

I.e. I don't want her coming in on the final minute and bringing it in for the touchdown/homerun/taking it the last mile.

Comment: It's on the tip of my tongue....  In the meantime, here are some vague approximations: *shanghai, hijack, commandeer*.

Answer (score 1):

There's the expression [**steal someone's thunder**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/steal%20someone%27s%20thunder):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : to prevent someone from having success or getting attention, praise, etc., by doing or saying whatever that person was planning to do or say
>   // I didn't mean to *steal your thunder*, but I just had to tell your mom about your promotion.

While it's a broader term, it does also apply to the specific situation you describe.

Somebody could come into a project after all the hard work has been done, present the result to management, and reap the reward for having accomplished the task:

> She came in after I'd done all the hard work and *stole my thunder*.